# Badge icons are missing in the Achievements when viewing from Area 51

Tags: bug, design, badges, area-51, achievements-dialog

When viewing the Achievements section from the Area 51 page, the badge icons are missing.

[image: Area 51 Achievements]

Where as viewing from other community page, the badge icons are displaying.

[image: SE Achievements]